# Hibernate, SQL in HQL (NativeQuery)

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, nativequery

I am starting out at Hibernate. I am at the point, where I try out SQL in HQL.
I saw a code example which I wanted to recreate, but my output ended up being different.
To use SQL in HQL, that person said, if you want to only use a couple of columns, you need to use a Map to get certain columns (So I can´t simply use addEntity here).
My Student table got sId, sName, sMarks. Now I want to retrieve only the Students names (sName) and their marks (sMarks).
The Problem is, that I only get "null" as values for the names and marks whilst the object shows me the proper values:

**Console Output:
Hibernate: SELECT sName,sMarks FROM student

{SNAME=Nameless fool number 1, SMARKS=65} 
null : null**

The Code:

```
NativeQuery querySQL2 = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT sName,sMarks "
            +                                   "FROM student");
querySQL2.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List students = querySQL2.getResultList();
for (Object o : students)
{
    System.out.println(o);
    Map m = (Map)o;
    System.out.println(m.get("sName") + " : " + m.get("sMarks"));
}
```

Why do I get the proper Object with Syso(o) and just null with Syso(m.get("..."))?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you already answered your question
`{SNAME=Nameless fool number 1, SMARKS=65}`. Hibernate convert column names to upper case.

Comment: This was it, thank you very much. I am working through a tutorial and that one got good reviews, but is from last year. Is it possible that this used to be different? I exchanged all deprecated functions with the current ones, but this did not cross my mind, cause he used small characters as well.
Thanks to you I learned another thing and that´s to not be too comfy with SQL, where it often does not matter if you use big or small characters.
Have a nice evening :)

Comment: Is there any mention of what db used in the tutorial? It may depend on it and on hibernate naming strategy as well. Check it out

Comment: Aaah! You are right! He was using MySQL and I am using Oracle SQL Developer. That could be it! I am prepping myself for a new Job and I get new topics. So I picked the database they use. Again, big thanks :)